# Expressing propositional function without quantifiers

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I have been following "Discrete Mathematics and its Applications" textbook by Rosen, 7th edition.

I have come across an exercise question (1.4, #20) that I am not sure how to answer. The book gives me the question and a bunch of choices that apply, but I'm not sure how I would solve and arrive at one of those answers.

> Suppose that the domain of the propositional function $P(x)$ consists of$ −5, −3, −1, 1, 3, \text{and}\ 5$. Express $\exists x(\lnot P(x))\land\forall x((x < 0) \to P(x))$ without using quantiﬁers, instead using only negations, disjunctions, and conjunctions. Click on the choice or choices which correspond to a correct solution:
>
> - $x$ cannot be any of the integers
> - $(x=-1)\land(x=-3)\land(x=-5)$
> - $\lnot(P(-5)\lor P(-3)\lor P(-1)\lor P(1)\lor P(3)\lor P(5))\land(x=-1)\land(x=-3)\land(x=-5)$
> - $(\lnot P(-5)\lor\lnot P(-3)\lor\lnot P(-1))\land(P(-5)\land P(-3)\land P(-1)$
> - $\lnot(P(-5)\lor P(-3)\lor P(-1)\lor P(3)\lor P(5))\land(P(-5)\land P(-3)\land P(-1))$
> - $\lnot P(-5)\land\lnot P(-3)\land\lnot P(-1)\land\lnot P(1)\land\lnot P(3)\land\lnot P(5)\land P(5)\land P(-5)\land P(-3)\land P(-1)$
> - $(\lnot P(-5)\lor\lnot P(-3)\lor\lnot P(-1)\lor\lnot P(1)\lor\lnot P(3)\lor\lnot P(5)\lor P(5))\land P(-5)\land P(-3)\land P(-1)$

How am I supposed to solve this and what's the correct answer?

Answer (score 1):

*Hint*

In a finite domain :

> $\exists x P(x)$ is equivalent to $P(x_0) \lor \ldots \lor P(x_n)$,

while :

> $\forall x P(x)$ is equivalent to : $P(x_0) \land \ldots P(x_n)$.

Thus, the part $∃x(¬P(x))$ is equivalent to :

> $¬P(-5) \lor ¬P(-3) \lor ¬P(-1) \lor ¬P(1) \lor ¬P(3) \lor ¬P(5)$.